# MySQL Multiple select from same table

Tags: mysql

I am building a bus reservation system. I am trying to query out a bus based on the trip selected.
I have in the tables Departure and Arrival for storing time.
I need to query out the Departure and the Arrival.

Below is my table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `bus_details` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Route` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `RouteCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BusCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CityCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Departure` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `Arrival` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `FromCityCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ToCityCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BusName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `sValid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `bus_details` (`ID`, `Route`, `RouteCode`, `BusCode`, `CityCode`, `City`, `Departure`, `Arrival`, `FromCityCode`, `ToCityCode`, `BusName`, `sValid`) VALUES
(48, 'Accra Mall - Papaye', 10001, 1001, 101, 'Accra Mall', '01:00:00', NULL, 101, 101, 'Sprinter', 1),
(49, 'Accra Mall - Papaye', 10001, 1001, 102, 'Flower Pot', '00:30:00', '01:15:00', 101, 102, 'Sprinter', 0),
(50, 'Accra Mall - Papaye', 10001, 1001, 103, 'Palace', '02:00:00', '00:45:00', 102, 103, 'Sprinter', 0),
(51, 'Accra Mall - Papaye', 10001, 1001, 104, 'Papaye', NULL, '02:30:00', 103, 104, 'Sprinter', 1),
(52, 'Accra Mall - Papaye', 10001, 1003, 101, 'Accra Mall', '02:00:00', NULL, 101, 101, 'VVIP Bus', 1),
(53, 'Accra Mall - Papaye', 10001, 1003, 102, 'Flower Pot', '02:30:00', '02:15:00', 101, 102, 'VVIP Bus', 0),
(54, 'Accra Mall - Papaye', 10001, 1003, 103, 'Palace', '03:00:00', '02:45:00', 102, 103, 'VVIP Bus', 0),
(55, 'Accra Mall - Papaye', 10001, 1003, 104, 'Papaye', NULL, '03:15:00', 103, 104, 'VVIP Bus', 1);

ALTER TABLE `bus_details`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);
```

I tried with

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.BusCode), t1.BusName, t1.CityCode, t1.FromCityCode, t2.ToCityCode, t1.Departure, t2.Arrival
FROM
    (SELECT BusName, BusCode, CityCode, FromCityCode, ToCityCode, Departure From bus_details Where CityCode IN(101) AND FromCityCode IN(101) Group By BusCode) As t1,
    (SELECT BusName, BusCode, CityCode, FromCityCode, ToCityCode, Arrival From bus_details Where CityCode IN(104) AND ToCityCode IN(104) Group By BusCode) As t2
```

Which was close to my expected answer but I returns 4 results as I expect to because only two buses are on this trip.

Within the four results two are correct and two is not.

Please can you help me with a correct query for this operation.

Thank you in advance

```
**Expected Output**
BusName   | tripFrom | tripTo | Departure | Arrival 
Sprinter     101          104    1:00:00    2:30:00    
VVIP Bus     101          104    2:30:00    3:15:00
```

This a sample of what I want my output to be.
Thanks again

Comment: Which was close to my expected answer but I returns 4 results as I expected 2 results because only two buses are on this trip.

---edited---

Comment: You might want to also add the expected output.

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: I want the BusName, tripFromCode, tripToCode, Departure And Arrival

Example as

**BusName | tripFrom  | tripTo | Departure | Arrival**
Sprinter        101           104       1:00:00      2:30:00
VVIP Bus      101           104       2:30:00      3:15:00

This is what I expect my output to be

Comment: Edit you question and add the expected output within the question dont use a comment for that.

Comment: What's the difference between CItyCode and ToCityCode and FromCityCode?

Comment: @Nick CityCode is same as FromCityCode and ToCityCode is where the bus is next travel is

Comment: I taught I could get some answers here looks like no one is coming. I have already added the output to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you are using a `JOIN` with no condition, so it is creating a cross-product of 2 bus routes x 2 bus routes = 4 results. If you had 3 routes you would have got 9 results. If you had included `t2.BusName` in your SELECT you would have seen all the cases where it was different to `t1.BusName`. You need to restrict the result by adding a condition that ensures the bus is the same on both routes i.e. `t1.BusCode = t2.BusCode` (or `t1.BusName = t2.BusName`)

```
SELECT t1.BusName, t1.FromCityCode AS tripFrom, t2.ToCityCode AS tripTo, t1.Departure, t2.Arrival
FROM
    (SELECT BusName, BusCode, CityCode, FromCityCode, ToCityCode, Departure 
     FROM bus_details 
     WHERE CityCode IN(101) AND FromCityCode IN(101) 
     GROUP BY BusCode) As t1
JOIN
    (SELECT BusName, BusCode, CityCode, FromCityCode, ToCityCode, Arrival 
     FROM bus_details 
     WHERE CityCode IN(104) AND ToCityCode IN(104)
     GROUP BY BusCode) As t2
ON t1.BusCode = t2.BusCode
```

Output ([Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32f91/17)):

```
BusName     tripFrom    tripTo  Departure   Arrival
Sprinter    101         104     01:00:00    02:30:00
VVIP Bus    101         104     02:00:00    03:15:00
```